# TypeError: User() got unexpected keyword arguments: 'reg_data_l' & You may need to make the field read-only, or override the UserSerializer.create()

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

`Models.py`

```
class User(AbstractUser, PermissionsMixin):
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_librarian = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_member = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Librarian(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    librarian_firstname = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    librarian_middlename = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    librarian_lastname = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    CATEGORY_GENDER = (('Male','Male'),('Female','Female'))
    librarian_gender = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=CATEGORY_GENDER)
    librarian_contact = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True, blank=True)
    librarian_photo = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'media/librarian_photo', default='media/default.webp', blank=True)
    librarian_address = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.librarian_firstname)+ ' - '+(self.librarian_lastname)
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for field_name in ['librarian_firstname', 'librarian_middlename', 'librarian_lastname']:
            val = getattr(self, field_name, False)
            if val:
                setattr(self, field_name, val.capitalize())
        super(Librarian, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

class Member(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    member_firstname = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    member_middlename = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    member_lastname = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    CATEGORY_GENDER = (('Male','Male'),('Female','Female'))
    member_gender = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=CATEGORY_GENDER)
    member_contact = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True, blank=True)
    member_photo = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'media/member_photo', default='media/default.webp', blank=True)
    member_address = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.member_firstname)+ ' - '+(self.member_lastname)
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for field_name in ['member_firstname', 'member_middlename', 'member_lastname']:
            val = getattr(self, field_name, False)
            if val:
                setattr(self, field_name, val.capitalize())
        super(Member, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    
class Books(models.Model):
    book_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    book_author = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    book_isbn = models.PositiveIntegerField()    

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.book_name)
```

`serializer.py`

```
class MemberSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Member
        fields = ('member_firstname','member_middlename','member_lastname','member_gender',
                  'member_contact','member_photo','member_address')

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    reg_data = MemberSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username','password','reg_data',)

        def create(self, validated_data):
            reg_info = validated_data.pop('reg_data')
            user_reg = User.objects.create(**validated_data)

            user_reg.set_password(validated_data['password'])
            user_reg.save()

            Member.objects.create(user=user_reg, **reg_info)
            obj = User.objects.get(id=user_reg.id)
            return obj

class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Books
        fields = ('book_name','book_author','book_isbn')

class LibrarianSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Librarian
        fields = ('librarian_firstname','librarian_middlename','librarian_lastname',
                  'librarian_gender','librarian_contact','librarian_photo','librarian_address')

class LibrarianUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    reg_data_l = LibrarianSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username','password','reg_data_l',)

        def create(self, validated_data):
            reg_info = validated_data.pop('reg_data_l')
            user_reg = User.objects.create(**validated_data)

            user_reg.set_password(validated_data['password'])
            user_reg.save()

            Librarian.objects.create(user=user_reg, **reg_info)
            obj = User.objects.get(id=user_reg.id)
            return obj
```

`Views.py`

```
class LibrarianAPI(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Librarian.objects.all()
    # authentication_classes = (JWTAuthentication, )
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated ,)
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

class MemberAPI(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Member.objects.all()
    # authentication_classes = (JWTAuthentication, )
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated ,)
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

class BooksAPI(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Books.objects.all()
    # authentication_classes = (JWTAuthentication, )
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated ,)
    serializer_class = BookSerializer
```

As a User

- I can signup either as LIBRARIAN and MEMBER using username and password
- I can login using username/password and get JWT access token

As a Librarian

- I can add, update, and remove Books from the system
- I can add, update, view, and remove Member from the system

As a Member

- I can view, borrow, and return available Books
- Once a book is borrowed, its status will change to BORROWED
- Once a book is returned, its status will change to AVAILABLE
- I can delete my own account

Please help i'm stuck into these & need your help. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are using reg_data_l in LibrarianUserSerializer whose meta-model is User but reg_data_l does not exist in the User model.

The problem is with this code.

```
class LibrarianUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    reg_data_l = LibrarianSerializer()

    class Meta:
         model = User
         fields = ('username','password','reg_data_l',)
```

Jest remove req_data_l if you are using this serializer for User Model.

Comment: Tried the way you said by removing the reg_data_l from serializer. But it's not working, still the same error